# How to query entities using google app engine from android?

Tags: java, android, sql, database, google-app-engine

I can retrieve a list of my entities and search through it that way.. However I can't have it retrieve the entire list this is taking to long. Is there any way I can query before I get the list.. I used tic tack toe example from google to build my app. My code is almost exactly the same. They have not one example for queries! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass a [`@Named` parameter](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#named) to the method on GAE and perform a query based on this parameter.

Sure they have a query example: see the [`list()` method](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-java/blob/master/src/com/google/devrel/samples/ttt/spi/ScoresV1.java#L63) in TicTacToe example. Also [in python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-python).

Comment: Oh and now that I think of it... For each run through in your list it doesn't actually add an object until you call the get function on one of its parameters.. Am I right?

Comment: Afaik no, Cloud Endpoints does not do lazy-loading. When you call that method it delivers the whole list with contents.